An inequality for an integral of a product
Let $f$ be some real valued function, and let $h$ be a positive function bounded above and away from zero. I wonder if it is true that
$$\bigg|\int h(x)f(x)dx \bigg| \leq (\sup(h)-\inf(h)) \bigg|\int f(x) dx\bigg|$$
or perhaps some estimates on the LHS of this sort in terms of $|\int f(x) dx|$? I'd also be interested in the cases where $h$ has compact support or some other more regular situations. Something tells me that due $h$'s bounds, one should be able to bound $|\int h(x)f(x)dx|$ above using $|\int f(x)dx|$ and something else, but another part of me tells me no because $f$ is possibly negative. Surely if $f$ is non-negative we would have something like $\int h(x)f(x)dx \leq \sup(h) \int f(x)dx$.

It may occur that $\int f(x),dx =0,$ while $\int h(x) f(x),dx \neq 0. Moreover $ If $f\ge 0$ adding a constant to $h$  does not change RHS but LHS will change its value.

Unfortunately you cannot conclude such a result. Consider $f(x) = \sin(x)$ and $h(x) = x$, and taking the integral within the bounds $[0, 2\pi]$. Then
\begin{align*}
\int_0^{2\pi} f(x) \ \mathrm{d}x &= 0\\
\int_0^{2\pi} h(x) f(x) \ \mathrm{d}x &= -2\pi\\
\end{align*}
but your inequality will not hold since the RHS is $0$ and the LHS is not $0$. At best, we can do the following:
\begin{align*}
\left |\int_a^b h(x) f(x) \ \mathrm{d}x \right | &\leq \left |\left (\sup_{x \in [a, b]} h(x) \right ) \int_a^b f^+(x) \ \mathrm{d}x - \left (\inf_{x \in [a, b]} h(x)\right ) \int_a^b f^-(x) \ \mathrm{d}x \right |
\end{align*}
where $f(x) = f^+(x) - f^-(x)$, with $f^+(x) = \max(0, f(x))$ and $f^-(x) = \max(0, -f(x))$.

Let $f(x)=h(x)=1$ for $a\le x\le b.$ Then RHS is equal $0$ while LHS is equal $b-a.$ So constant sign of $f$ does not help.
